# GoLang, what is contents in parenthesis before MethodName?

Tags: go

```
func (t *T) MethodName(argType T1, replyType *T2) error
```

what is contents in parenthesis before MethodName? I mean this (t *T)

This  comes from here: http://golang.org/pkg/net/rpc/
I try to understand golang rpc and saw this method definition.

Thanks,

Comment: @peterSO's answer is exactly right, but this is also a very basic part of Go syntax. If you're unfamiliar with it, you should take a few minutes and go through the tutorial at tour.golang.org. Go does a lot of things very differently (sometimes radically differently) from other languages, so it can be tricky to try to intuit what's going on based on previous experience. For example, the term `MethodName` might make you think that `T` is a class and `t` is an object. But that's not the right way to think about them in Go, and you can get lost pretty quickly if you do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Method declarations](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations)
>
> A method is a function with a receiver. A method declaration binds an
>   identifier, the method name, to a method, and associates the method
>   with the receiver's base type.
>
> Given type Point, the declarations

```
func (p *Point) Length() float64 {
    return math.Sqrt(p.x * p.x + p.y * p.y)
}

func (p *Point) Scale(factor float64) {
    p.x *= factor
    p.y *= factor
}
```

> bind the methods Length and Scale, with receiver type *Point, to the
>   base type.

It's the method receiver.

Comment: Adding another sentence from the specification might help the reader to better understand what is happening:
"The method is said to be bound to its receiver base type T and the method name is visible only within selectors for type T or *T."